# Exception Due to Type Missing From Assembly (Revised)

Tags: c#, .net

I have made some progress on the problem I posted about yesterday, so I am rewriting the post.

My problem appears to be related to my use of generics. Here's the relevant part of App.config (formatted with whitespace for readability):

```
<configSections>
    <section
        name="NA5300ResolverSynchroDevices"
        type="InfrastructureModule.DeviceConfiguration.DeviceConfigurationSection
             &lt;NA5300ResolverSynchroModule.NA5300ResolverSynchroConfigurationElement&gt;,
             NA5300ResolverSynchroModule">
    </section>
</configSections>

<NA5300ResolverSynchroDevices>
    <Device deviceName="AzResolverSynchro" busAddress="7"/>
    <Device deviceName="ElResolverSynchro" busAddress="8"/>
</NA5300ResolverSynchroDevices>
```

Here's the class I'm trying to map to the configuration section:

```
namespace InfrastructureModule.DeviceConfiguration
{
    public class DeviceConfigurationSection<T> : ConfigurationSection
           where T : DeviceConfigurationElement, new()
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("", IsDefaultCollection = true, IsKey = false)]
        public DeviceConfigurationElementCollection<T> Devices
        {
            get { return (DeviceConfigurationElementCollection<T>) base[""]; }
            set { base[""] = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the C# code that tries to access the config file:

```
DeviceConfigurationSection<NA5300ResolverSynchroConfigurationElement> devices =
    ConfigurationManager.GetSection("NA5300ResolverSynchroDevices") as
    DeviceConfigurationSection<NA5300ResolverSynchroConfigurationElement>;
```

Here's the exception text I'm getting:

> > An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for NA5300ResolverSynchroDevices: Could not load type 'InfrastructureModule.DeviceConfiguration.DeviceConfigurationSection<NA5300ResolverSynchroModule.NA5300ResolverSynchroConfigurationElement>' from assembly 'NA5300ResolverSynchroModule'.

I know that in C# generics are instantiated at runtime rather than at compile time (unlike C++). I do not yet know enough about generics to understand what assembly a runtime-generated type is considered to live in when the generic type and the instantiating type live in different assemblies. Above, I told the runtime to look for it in assembly NA5300ResolverSynchroModule. I've also tried telling it to look for it in assembly InfrastructureModule. Neither works.

I am attempting to use a genric type because I will have many config sections for which the corresponding ConfigurationSection-derived types will all be of the form shown above. I want to avoid code duplication.

Can anybody see why my approach is failing and how I can fix it?

Comment: It's due to the way it's creating the configuration handler. What does the config section look like?

Comment: This exception would be caused if the type was not in the assembly. .NET isn't inventing this, or lying to you. It really does need that type, and it really isn't in that assembly. You need to investigate to find out how that could possibly be true.

Comment: <NA5300ResolverSynchroDevices>
    <Device deviceName="AzResolverSynchro" busAddress="7"/>
    <Device deviceName="ElResolverSynchro" busAddress="8"/>
</NA5300ResolverSynchroDevices>

Comment: Thank you kindly to whoever cleaned up my post!

Comment: The exception text is actually as follows (the editor killed the content between angle brackets):

An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for NA5300ResolverSynchroDevices: Could not load type 'InfrastructureModule.DeviceConfiguration.DeviceConfigurationSection<NA5300ResolverSynchroModule.NA5300ResolverSynchroConfigurationElement>' from assembly 'NA5300ResolverSynchroModule'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is actually how you've referenced the generic type.

Instead of (shortened):

```
<section name="..."
type="InfrastructureModule.DeviceConfiguration.DeviceConfigurationSection
             &lt;NA5300ResolverSynchroModule.NA5300ResolverSynchroConfigurationElement&gt;,
             NA5300ResolverSynchroModule" />
```

Try

```
<section name="..."
type="InfrastructureModule.DeviceConfiguration.DeviceConfigurationSection`1[[NA5300ResolverSynchroModule.NA5300ResolverSynchroConfigurationElement, NA5300ResolverSynchroModule]],
             NA5300ResolverSynchroModule" />
```

Note the  *`1[[...]]*  rather than *<...>* or *&lt;...&gt;* part for the generic type.  The part inside the [[...]] can be a full type definition as well - like namespace.class,assembly,token.

The `1 is "generic type with one type parameter".  If the type takes 2 "aka SomeType<T,V>", use`2.  Note that you should put "type, assembly" in the double square brackets, not just "type"

Comment: Well, it turns out I'm still not quite there. I tried both a forward tick (') and a backward tick (`), and I tried both InfrastructureModule and NA5300ResolverSynchroModule for the assembly. That's four combinations, and all resulted in an exception still indicating the required type could not be found in the assembly I specified. I think this is really close though. Is there some syntactic tweak that needs to be made to your suggestion?

Comment: For the record it's backtick, 1, double square brackets:  `1[[  - Are both of the types in the same assembly?

Comment: Your latest suggestions have led me to success. Here's what ultimately ended up working:
      type="InfrastructureModule.DeviceConfiguration.DeviceConfigurationSection`1[[NA5300ResolverSynchroModule.DeviceConfiguration.NA5300ResolverSynchroConfigurationElement, NA5300ResolverSynchroModule]], InfrastructureModule"/>

As can be seen above, the generic type and the instantiating type are not in the same assembly.

Thank you very kindly for the help; this is much better than the solution I had come up with!

Answer (score 0):

I believe my problem was rooted in the fact that the runtime-generated type I tried to map to a configuration section does not live in an assembly. So, I created a type that *does* live in an assmebly.

```
namespace NA5300ResolverSynchroModule
{
    public class NA5300ResolverSynchroDeviceConfigurationSection :
            DeviceConfigurationSection<NA5300ResolverSynchroConfigurationElement>
    {
    }
}
```

I can reference NA5300ResolverSynchroDeviceConfigurationSection just fine in App.config.

Comment: It's not the location of your generic type, it's actually the syntax in your app.config.